# Create pages from databse Using php [Like what framework or cms are doing ]

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, .htaccess

Hi i have a database table and a php form in which i can insert table entry . For example i have a form in which i can add post title and post content . So in the table i have 4 column **(1)post_id**, **(2)post_title**, **(3)post_content**, **(4)post_url**.  So currently i fill the form with **title="red color" content="red** color is so bright and attractive ". so it will store on database.

Now what i need is when there is an entry in table i have to generate page url also . Here it is `example.com/red-color.` 
And some on can take `example.com/red-color` i need to display the content , and google boot need to automatically fetch through page .

I know this is some complicated process like what wordpress is doing when user insert the content to the post then it will create new page with unique url .

I need only some basic ideas for to proceed .

> If anyone know please share the knowledge .

Answer (score 7):

First: you need to have mechanism to redirect all you requests to your router.
In case of Apache you can add .htaccess file with next content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

In case of Nginx (part of sample config, the main logic is in @rewrite stream and try_files directive)

```
server {
    ....

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    ## Execute PHP scripts
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

in index.php file you will have access to Path which was originally requested `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`

and here(in index.php file): (if that variable set) try to lookup value of `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` in your table, in case if you find that: display title, content and so on.
In case if you can not find it - you should dispaly 404 page (with information that post wasn't found)

In simpliest approach - that is.

Good luck :)

Comment: yes this is giving good ideas . This is very helpful friend . I will check this and get back to you .

Comment: friend i giving  bonus point for this  answer. If you get more ideas about this topic please update this post . It will help more

Comment: What's the problem do you have with that now ? I can not update answer if I do not have question :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you know how to create/insert post in wordpress, now the important part is you want to create custom end-points like frameworks, so in my views you should check WordPress REST API.

[Adding custom endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), this will give you better idea about it. You can also look at woocommerce end points, how my-account page is created in woocommerce, that is also thee end-point concept.This [gist](https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/a79f4e3992ae96cb821d3b357834a005) has some code to create custom end point, you can look into it. I have used it in few of my projects, if you need I can share it with you.

In core PHP, you can create routes and handle requests based on URL, HTTP verbs and query parameters.

Basic Example

**rotes.php**

```
<?php
$router->define([
    'project' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'project/about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'project/contact' => 'controllers/contact.php',
]);
```

**Router class**

```
class Router
{
    protected $routes = [];
    public function define($routes){
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri){
        if ( array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes) ){
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No routes defined!');
    }

    public static function load($file){
        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'core/bootstrap.php';
require Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri());
```

**boostrap.php**

```
<?php
$app = [];
$app['config'] = require 'config.php';
require 'core/Router.php';
require 'core/Request.php';
require 'core/database/Connection.php';
require 'core/database/QueryBuilder.php';

$app['database'] = new QueryBuilder(
    Connection::make($app['config']['database'])
);
```

**Request Class**

```
<?php
class Request
{
    public static function uri(){
        return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    }
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /project/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   #RewriteRule ^(.*)project/(.*)$ /index.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If you look `boostarp.php` that will give you folder structure and I hope this will give you idea about routing and MVC.

*You may like to remove `project/` if you do not want it inside folder or you have created a virtual host (in your local machine).*

Comment: this is good point friend . But the thing is that i am not taking about custom end point in wordpress . I just talk about it as an example . so that i can apply this for normal php

Comment: In normal PHP, you need to create routes, for request type, url and query parameters. If you want I can edit my answer, I have created a very basic mvc framework, so the implementation is very very basic, you will get an idea, but I will not suggest using that in live projects.

Comment: @abilasher, now check my answer, I hope this will guide you.

Comment: yes friend , can you please explain in which stage this code is taking the title from the database and creating the url based on the title ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177854/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-abilash-er).

Comment: I have old you how the system works, storing the URLs in database is just matter of choice and you can retrieve and parse it similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/, Also make sure the pemalink structure is set in wp-admin

```
    $color    = "red color" ;
    $content  = "red color is so bright and attractive ";
    $slug     = "red-color";
    $postarr  = array('post_title' => $color,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_name' => $slug
              );

    // The post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on failure.
    wp_insert_post($postarr)
```

Answer (score -1):

First, for "Clean URL", you need edit `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /showpage.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Script showpage.php :

```
<?php
IF (isset($_GET["page"]))
  {
  $URL=$_GET["page"];  
  $DTB->new mysqli($Mysql_Server,$Mysql_User,$Mysql_Password,$Mysql_Database);
  $PageData = $DTB->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_url ='URL' LIMIT 1");
  IF ($PageData->num_rows>0)
    {
    $Data=$PageData->fetch_array();
    echo('... html code of header etc.');
    echo('<body>'.$DATA["post_content"].'</body>');
    echo('... html code of footer etc.');
    }
  else
    {
    // show error404.page or redirect to index
    }
  }
?>
```

I cant help you with google bot "readable", maybe this ? 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en